# Does a prestigious internship (at google) help for PhD programs in Computer Science?

Tags: graduate-admissions

If I have the option of choosing between a (non-research) internship at Google and a REU program at a non-prestigious university, which one should I select? After graduation, I intend to pursue a PhD in Computer Science, hopefully in machine learning.

Which of the two offers should I accept to improve graduate admissions? What if the intern position is directly in what I want to work in, i.e. machine learning?

I know research is valued more for graduate admissions, but a machine learning internship at google seems like a valuable asset.

Comment: While it would likely help, it really depends on what you get to do at Google.

Comment: What matters is the quality of the recommendation letter you can get as a result.

Comment: In what sense is a non-research internship at Google “prestigious”?

Comment: @JeffE in an industry sense (which would beg the question - what do you want this for?)

Comment: @xuq01 : this reminds me of a certain minister of social services in a certain country, who used that he worked before at a very prestigious international charity organization, implying he was a manager there... and later it turned out he worked there as a driver.

Comment: Work experience is very valuable even in Academic Research. I would go for the internship.

Comment: I think the answers will really depend on the specifics. Sweeping the floors at Google is not prestigious; doing research would be. It sounds like you are somewhere in the middle, but I'm not sure what that would be (do they let interns write production code?).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was exactly in your position a year before finishing my master’s. I was in touch with Google regarding an internship (I've passed their interviews and could've accepted as soon as we matched me with a topic). The timing for the Google internship didn't fit brilliantly with my university schedule (we had the longest semester in Europe back in the time), so I went to talk to my advisor at the time to ask him whether he thinks I should take the internship despite it colliding with three weeks of my classes.

I was at the time seriously considering following up my master’s with a PhD programme, and he knew that when I came for advice. His response was that if that's my plan, I would benefit much more from a research internship – and then he proceeded to arrange one for me (and one more the following year; he really was brilliant and dedicated advisor).

I agree that through an industry internship you will acquire [skills Allure mentions in his answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/123916/4249), and I do admit I lack some of them even now. On the other hand, **taking the research internships got me into a PhD programme**. Some concrete benefits I got from there (somewhat location dependant):

- I got into my first proper research group. While my master’s advisor was golden, research is not too strong in my country of origin.
- It got me a non-generic, research-oriented letter of recommendation
- Inquiring about PhD positions through e-mail has a very low response rate; even if you don't ask about publicly available information and only ask about advertised positions through proper channels.
- Politely knocking on somebody's door and saying "Hi, I'm doing an internship in the group down the hall and saw you advertising a PhD position. I was wondering if you have five minutes one of these days to talk about it a bit" had a much higher response rate.
- I got coached for the admissions process by my advisers-to-be, as they decided to support me as a candidate following that five-minute conversation mentioned in the previous point.

I do have a feeling the benefits were quite tangible as I come from a fairly small country, my master’s university was not particularly famous and there is not much research support. Thus, being at a research institute and in direct contact with several research groups gave me connections and opened some doors for me which would have been much more difficult to achieve otherwise.

All that said; taking a machine-learning internship at Google will surely not harm your profile or your CV. Just remember – it is a software engineering internship and therefore will give you those skills; if you want to focus on your research skills it is not a best choice. If you want to experience a bit of everything before committing (to a PhD, say), it just might be.

Answer (score 38):

Take the internship. It's not so much about whether it helps for graduate admissions or not, but rather how it is going to broaden your horizons. If you do the REU program, when you start the PhD, you're going to be doing similar things. On the other hand taking the internship gives you firsthand experience you cannot otherwise get:

- What working in the real world is like
- What skills are actively useful in industry
- What skills you currently lack, but can learn in a PhD
- What kind of job you can do if you get a PhD, but can't do now

(This neglects the financial aspect entirely, plus the fact that you're still going to be learning things during the internship which you can write into your application.) These things are likely to change your view of the PhD entirely. In the extreme case, you might find you don't want to do a PhD anymore. Less extremely, you'll have a better idea why you're studying, what you want to learn, and how that is going to help you.

tl; dr: do the different thing, because it'll act as a great enabler even if it's not immediately helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Acceptance on any program is, or should be, based on your attributes, capacities and skills. Ie it is not **where** you did the internship, but what you learnt from it...

Answer (score 1):

In general, an internship at google has a good reputation. If it is in the desired field, it would be my choice. Especially if it is in machine learning, you are in a very good place (assuming you are not just cooking coffee ;-) )!

The most important is what you learned during the internship, and this includes cs skills as well as company culture, work ethics, etc.

You should consider which knowledge / skills you are lacking and which of the two position helps you in filling that gap. E.g. if you did nearly no research until now, the research group might be a better idea (maybe you figure out that you hate research afterwards ;-) - and/or you are gaining research skills), if you need to learn practical software development and want to know the real world, an internship in industry is favourable.

Comment: Um. Google internships wouldn't have a good reputation if they were just about making the coffee. (Though making coffee is a valuable skill to bring into any CS department.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby How about building a coffee machine that can be controlled by voice and can learn from your ratings ("Hey Google, your coffee is too acid/too bitter/perfect")? That can lead to a PhD in HCI (Human-Coffee interaction).

Comment: @user4052054 what about a camera to check the coffee level in the machine? Oh, been done already....

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on some factors not mentioned in the question. Some points to consider:

1) I'd say, as a rule PhD programs are not overcrowded, so I am not sure whether *"improving the chance of admission"* is an issue at all for a reasonably skillful student. (Unless you are aiming at some really high-profile institution and you know for sure that there is a serious competition even at PhD level).

2) However, if you are planning to obtain financial support for your PhD studies, it's a completely different story. Competition for scholarships can be severe, but again, if you know that a certain department offers N scholarships, it does not mean that they only have N vacant places for PhD students.

3) When you apply for a scholarship, regulations vary. Say, at my institution they mostly pay attention to specific predefined points (such as scientific publication record), so Google internship won't help in this case. However, the process is funder-specific, so you'd better find out the prescribed criteria if you can.

Comment: joining a PhD program in CS without financial support would indicate that you are at a university you would have been better off avoiding (at least in Europe and  North America). So your entire first part is inaccurate.

Comment: Why? I can name you at least one top British university (~top 10 in CS field in the UK), having a large number of self-funded PhD students from affluent families, who can afford tuition. Everything is not so black and white, places with high reputation attract everyone, including people who don't need scholarships.

Comment: I disagree on Phd programs are not over crowded.  Competition is fierce for good positions.  My uni offers 40 places out of ~300 applicants every year on average.

Comment: @Koenig Lear, Yes, I can't speak for all institutions. Do you mean you provide 40 positions without any financial support?

Comment: @rg_software.  These 40 positions are just related to application process. Funding is "separate"  It's more related to availability of professors to student ratios and applicant talent.  Most people are funded by the university or government.    A minority (<10%) does get self-funded.   Naturally if you say you're self-funded you improve your chances.

Comment: Somebody who can get an internship at Google is going to be looking to do a PhD at a strong institution. Such institutions are _always_ over-subscribed.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I beg to differ: internships and PhD positions are not *solely* awarded based on skills; there is a quite big component (especially in the latter) that is played by whether or not your former/current advisor provides a strong recommendation (which in turn may not be connected at all with how good you are).

Comment: @gented I actually disagree with you about the Google internship specifically, having gone through the process. They don't read any letters, and you have to get through several rounds of phone interviews - focused on programming skills and algorithmics. Which is why I don't necessarily agree with DavidRicherby either - they're not going to be looking for just 'any PhD', but you need much more than strong programming skills and ability to quickly analyse problems (especially if it has mainly been applied to algorithms) to be a strong PhD candidate (tho those characteristics are a great start).

Comment: @penelope Yes sure, I agree. What I meant was that landing a position at Google does not necessarily imply one will get a good PhD, nor is it true that after having landed a good PhD then you are assured a position in a high profile company.

Comment: @gented Landing an internship at Google and landing a "position" at Google are two different things (judging by the amount of scrutiny one is put under in the interview process). Also, while I haven't met any rock-star researchers straight after their PhD (they might get treated differently by the big G and offered a research post), what other people get when invited to a job interview by Google after their PhD's is explicitly and directly "_We are aware that you spent the last X years in a PhD programme, we will take it into account and not take it too much against you._"

Comment: @penelope I don't understand your last sentence - nobody said that either the internship or the PhD will be held against the candidate. My point, once again, is that you might land an Academic position in a prestigious university and fail outside and likewise be successful in industry (whether this is an internship or a full position) and be neglected in Academia - therefore the statement "internship at Google <---> good PhD" is not necessarily valid.

Comment: @gented Sorry, this was just me venting a bit. That sentence was almost exactly, word-for-word, what I got told by my Google recruiter after my PhD. So, at least some people in Google _will_ take a PhD against you (tho I got a very strong feeling that it was a much more wide-spread opinion than just that of my recruiter; I got re-assured repeatedly that my interviewers will be familiar that I spent the last 3+ years specializing and will not _take it against me too much_). Needless to say, I went to academia in the end, where my previous research experience woundn't be taken against me one bit

Comment: @gented I agree that _you_ didn't say that a PhD or an internship would be held against the candidate regardless of future career choices. But somebody in fact did say that, and at that somebody who's opinion on the topic very much did matter. Sorry if it came across as criticising what you said, I was just offering additional info based on personal experience related to what you said, rather than trying to correct you.

Answer (score 0):

What Google and Amazon do with machine learning is so far on the "applied sciences" side of things that it's probably irrelevant to your studies.

Their AI/ML projects are about throwing existing algorithms at existing data, and very little research is done in-house.

[Relevant Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/SimonDeDeo/status/1017616703864307712)

Comment: They do research, see AlphaZero, Word2vec etc.  However it's unlikely that an intern with a BS/MS in CS would land there.

Comment: In 2017, Google had [more papers](https://medium.com/machine-learning-in-practice/nips-accepted-papers-stats-26f124843aa0) accepted at NIPS than the MIT (or any other university). I'm quite sure these numbers were similar last year.

Comment: well this is just wrong, and the twitter thread looks more like a rant than anything else. He has some good point, but he takes them way too far. Are you telling me word2vec or alphazero have not changed the field significantly? Or are they also something that he could do in 2 weeks with a random master student? (roll eyes)